# Alpine Linux 3.18.3 - Kernel pinning during installation

Tags: kernel, alpine-linux

I'm a new Alpine Linux user and I'm struggling to install a specific kernel version on **Alpine-virt-3.18.3-x86_64**. The ISO I'm using comes with the default kernel version 6.1.43-0-virt. When I run the setup-alpine script, it automatically upgrades the kernel to version 6.1.79-r0. However, for testing purposes, I want to pin the kernel version to **6.1.46-0-virt**. What's the correct way to do this? Current kernel version:

```
alpine3:/sbin# uname -a
Linux alpine3 6.1.43-0-virt #1-Alpine SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 04 Aug 2023 06:44:47 +0000 x86_64 Linux
```

I tried to use following Alpine scripts without any luck

```
apk search

./setup-disk -k 6.1.46-0-virt

./update-kernel -f 6.1.46-0-virt
```

Is there a specific repo which I need to add so that I can pin the kernel version to  **kernel version to 6.1.46-0-virt** ?

Thanks